# How can i get the id from specific objects of an array?

Tags: php

i need to display from an array with 141 movies, the 10 oldest films. After i do this i need to make each one of them a link to their pages with the description of the movie.
So, i used this to get the oldest movies:

```
$movies = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegor-sytnyk/movies-list/master/db.json'))->movies;

$numbers = array_column($movies, 'year','title');
$numbers2=asort($numbers, SORT_NUMERIC);
$numbers3=array_slice($numbers, 0, 10);
```

And to make the link i used this:

```
<?php foreach($numbers3 as $key=>$value){?>
<a href="single.php?movie_id"><?php echo "$key-$value",'<br>';?></a>
<?php }?>
```

And also the single.php page:

```
$movieId=$_GET['movie_id'];
if(isset($movieId)&& $movieId && $movieId !=""){
    function get_movie($value){
        global $movieId;
        if($movieId==$value->id){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    $moviesFilter=array_filter($movies, "get_movie", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
    if(count($moviesFilter)>0){
        $movie= reset($moviesFilter);
    }?>

 <?php}?>
```

And i can't find the id's from that 10 specific movies to display the content after i press on them...:(

Comment: @B001ᛦ You can see it by going to [the endpoint](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegor-sytnyk/movies-list/master/db.json)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing equal sign ("=") here:

```
<a href="single.php?movie_id"><?php echo "$key-$value",'<br>';?></a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="single.php?movie_id=<?php echo $movie_id?>" ><?php echo $key-$value; ?></a><br/>
```

Just add (temporary) something like:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

...at top of single.php script to see what values you receive when you click the link.

Comment: hmm, now when i press on link the page appears, but without the content of the movie.

Comment: Still wrong, it should be <a href="single.php?movie_id=<?php echo $key-$value ?>> <?php echo $key-$value?></a>

Comment: i received this: Array ( [movie_id] => )

Comment: Check on generated html (page) source. href must be something like "single.php?movie_id=45". Btw, it's good to use "root relative paths", so path would be "/single.php..." (starting with slash sign) so link will work from any page.

Comment: Generally, you know how your link must look like, so adjust it until you get valid html in you page source.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use the real ID of the movie as an argument:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegor-sytnyk/movies-list/master/db.json'), true);
$movies = array_key_exists('movies', $data) ? $data['movies'] : [];
$filtered_movies = $movies;

uasort( $filtered_movies, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['year'] - $b['year'];
});
$filtered_movies = array_slice($filtered_movies, 0, 10);

foreach ($filtered_movies as $id => $movie) {
?>
    <a href="single.php?movie_id=<?= $id ?>"><?= $movie['year']." - ".$movie['title'] ?></a>
<?php
}
```

json_decode offers to decode into an associative array, rather than an Object. For this scenario, this is the more favorable solution. Now, getting the movie by unique ID is also a bit prettier in `single.php`:

```
$movieId = $_GET['movie_id'];                                                   
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegor-sytnyk/movies-list/master/db.json'), true);
$movies = array_key_exists('movies', $data) ? $data['movies'] : [];             

if (array_key_exists($movieId, $movies)) {                                      
?>                                                                              
Movie details:<br>                                                              
Title: <?= $movies[$movieId]['title'] ?><br>                                    
Year: <?= $movies[$movieId]['year'] ?><br>                                      
Genres: <?= join(', ', $movies[$movieId]['genres']) ?><br>                      

<?php                                                                           
} else {                                                                        
?>                                                                              
    The desired movie does not exist.                                           
<?php                                                                           

}
```

Comment: i can't echo $movie

Comment: Yes, because it's an array containing all the fields. This is why I made it like output both the year and the title: `<?= $movie['year']." - ".$movie['title'] ?>`